# what are annotations in hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

briefly, can someone tell me what an annotation is in hiberate? (java)

is it a way to quickly map entities to tables?

Comment: Huh.  Stack overflow denies links to LMGTFY.  A shame.  Here's a good link on Hibernate Annotations.  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec

Answer (score 1):

Its way more than that. In hibernate they are used to tell the tools that process your code the meaning of the parts of your code. So

```
 @Entity
 public class MyClass{}
```

will be processed (that is the code itself will be read) and the @Entity annotation indicates that the MyCLass class is an Entity - represents real world data.

A similar thing can be achieved with xml files but that would required managing multiple files.

So in a way it allows you to specify meta data about your code.

Comment: Thats right. They provide a similar function and they both support custom attributes or annotations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Hibernate annotations are used on domain classes, instead of using mapping files (hibernate.cfg.xml, etc.). I guess you can google about details. Briefly, it is a more convenient way to define your mappings and their attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Basically your annotations are your analogous of the xml config that's all there is to it, so therefore the annotations equivalent of

```
<property name="description" column="descriptive_text" />
```

is

```
@Column(name="descriptive_text")
private String description;
```

Keep in mind that `@Column` is the JPA standard (`@javax.persistence.Column`) of which Hibernate is an implementation. There are, of course, Hibernate specific annotations like `@org.hiberanate.annotations.Immutable` which specifies that an entity or collection are immutable. Further info [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/).